# How do I return only the first instance of a Regex match versus a whole group of them?

Tags: regex

I have a regex string which is working flawlessly on returning any numbers in a time format however I only need it to return the first match and not a group of 30 separate times all at once.

The syntax is:

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$
```

It returns 12:30 for instance if it is on the page but then it will also return 1:30 then 2:30 etc......

Is there any way to get this syntax to just return one time it finds instead of a list of 30 or 50?

Comment: What language or text editor? What regex flavor?

Answer (score 0):

Regex does this by default, however a lot of different languages or tools may apply a **global** match by default, which means that it *does not stop* after the first matched instance.

---

A guide on JavaScript Regular Expressions can be found here: [Regular Expressions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Look at the section on [**Advanced Searching with Flags**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags)

A regexp object with the global flag looks like this `/regex/g;`
So a non-global search would simply be `/regex/;`

Comment: I believe it is the Javascript flavor of Regex.